# How to get string out of string

Tags: php

I have a long string and part of that string is this: `<span itemprop="ratingValue">9.26</span>`. I want to get 9.26 as a string (using explode?). Thanks for any help. PS: it is html code saved as string.

Comment: You should use an HTML parser library, such as `DOMDocument`.

Comment: use preg_match and regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match()`:

```
$input = 'verylongstring<withother>random</withother>
          tags<span itemprop="ratingValue"><9.26</span>';
preg_match('~<span itemprop="ratingValue">(.*?)</span>~', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // 9.26
```

Comment: *"a long string and part of that string is"*… this'll probably match a bit too much…

Comment: It can contain no' of tags.